# ORACLE APEX custom authentication issue

Tags: oracle-apex

I created custom authentication in my application.
Function:

Set this function in my current custom authentication scheme.

In login page, pre-rendering get username cookie is as follows: :P9999_USERNAME := apex_authentication.get_login_username_cookie;

Despite all the settings, i am unable to login from any user apart from admin.

What am i missing here which is throwing error while logging as any othe user.

Error is something like this:

*

```
This page can only be used by the Admin!!
Access denied by Page security check
Technical Info (only visible for developers)
is_internal_error: true
apex_error_code: APEX.AUTHORIZATION.ACCESS_DENIED
component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_AUTHORIZATION
component.id: 8437237202059640757
component.name: Admin Pages
error_backtrace:
----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
0x4c2808328      1039  package body APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR.INTERNAL_GET_ERROR
0x4c2808328      1107  package body APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR.INTERNAL_ADD_ERROR
0x4c2808328      1499  package body APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR.RAISE_INTERNAL_ERROR
0x4ecaeb950       874  package body APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_AUTHORIZATION.IS_AUTHORIZED
0x51d27c1b0      3016  package body APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW.SHOW
```

*

Comment: Vini, did you still need help with this or did Scott's answer help?

Comment: i got this fixed,thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're conflating authentication with authorisation.

You're letting the user in, but directing them to a page protected by an authorisation scheme. Perhaps allow authenticated users into your home page, but add 'before header' branches conditional by authorisation scheme to redirect them to their relevant page.